# pandas Series is a latex object: how to convert back to normal pd.Series()?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks normal when I examine it in jupyter, but when I call a column it shows:

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
{} &    Overlap \\
\midrule
0  &    110/136 \\
1  &        4/5 \\
2  &      53/62 \\
3  &        5/5 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

However, when I write `type(df.c1)` it shows `pandas.core.series.Series`. How can I convert it back to a "normal" series? I want to process the strings in this series and cannot with the standard `pd.Series().str.split('/')`

Edit:

```
df.dtypes
# out:
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
{} &        0 \\
\midrule
c1 &   object \\
c2 &   object \\
c3 &  float64 \\
c4 &  float64 \\
c5 &   object \\
c6 &   object \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

type(df)
#pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

(the col I want to examine is `c2`).

Comment: What happens when you call `type(df)` and `df.dtypes`?

Comment: @Tom, I have updated my post to show you the output of your commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many rows does this series have?

If it has only 1 row the most likely explanation is that you stored the latex table as a string inside the row.

Comment: If I run `df.c2.index` I can see it has 268 indices